# Lua SQL Escape String (Try) Unfinished String near '"}'

Tags: string, lua, escaping

```
function escape_sqli(source)
    to_replace = {"'", '"'}
    replace_with = {"\'", '\"'}
    output = source
    for i = 1, table.getn(to_replace) do
        output = string.gsub(output, to_replace[i], replace_with[i])
    end
    return output
end
```

I tried the code above to Escape SQLis but I get the following error when I try to compile it:

```
Unfinished String near '"}'
```

Comment: The code looks syntactically correct. Note that `"'"` and `"\'"` are both a string with a single quote;  `'"'` and `'\"'` are both a string with a double quote, there is no backslash in those string literals.

Comment: what line gives the error?

Comment: the error occures in line 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it currently is, there is no syntactical error in [the code](http://codepad.org/YEwoX5v4).

---

A suggestion though; From [`string.gsub`](http://devdocs.io/lua/index#pdf-string.gsub) documentation:

> ## string.gsub (s, pattern, repl [, n])
>
> [...]
>
> If `repl` is a table, then the table is queried for every match, using
>   the first capture as the key.

You can simply recreate replacement tables as follows:

```
local replacements = { ['"'] = '\\"', ["'"] = "\\'" }
```

and use it in a single `gsub` call:

```
function escape_sqli(source)
    local replacements = { ['"'] = '\\"', ["'"] = "\\'" }
    return source:gsub( "['\"]", replacements ) -- or string.gsub( source, "['\"]", replacements )
end
```

Comment: Executing this on the http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo gets me this error:
input:3: bad argument #1 to 'gsub' (string expected, got table)

Comment: you need a pattern argument, like `'.'` or `'["\']'`

Comment: @rpattiso Yeah! Forgot about pattern entirely :P Fixed now. Thanks :)